# Opencv functions was not declared

Tags: opencv3.0

I switched to new opencv 3.0 as it is newer and has more function, but I faced with a problem.
When I compile old code which was perfectly working on version 2.4.8, it could not find some function:

```
error: ‘resize’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘VideoCapture’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘namedWindow’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘cvtColor’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘imshow’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘Sobel’ was not declared in this scope
```

here the small piece of code as an example:

test.cpp:

```
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) 
{
    IplImage* imgX;
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );

    Sobel(img, imgX, CV_32F, 1, 0, 1);

    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage( "Example1", imgX );    
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &imgX );
    cvDestroyWindow("Example1");
}
```

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Test)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable(Test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries( Test ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

and output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target Test
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test.cpp.o
/home/kairat/Dropbox/ComputerVision/Codes/test/test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/kairat/Dropbox/ComputerVision/Codes/test/test.cpp:11:34: error: ‘Sobel’ was not declared in this scope
  Sobel(img, imgX, CV_32F, 1, 0, 1);
                                  ^
CMakeFiles/Test.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What I could do in this situation?

Comment: please do **not** use IplImage* or cv* functions any more (opencv did away with that 5 years ago), instead use cv:Mat consistantly. also please use c++ headers, like "opencv2/opencv.hpp", not the outdated c headers, like "opencv/cv.h"

Answer (score 1):

Sobel(img, imgX, CV_32F, 1, 0, 1); this is c++ version of sobel function.

you should use c version of sobel function 
i.e cvSobel(img, imgX,1, 0, 1); as you are dealing with C structure IPLimage.
Note:C version of opencv functions generally starts with "cv".

Otherwise convert your IPLimages to Mats using this function 
Mat src = cvarrToMat(img) then use Sobel(src , srcX, CV_32F, 1, 0, 1);
it is recommended to use the c++ functions by dealing with Mats which has more advantages like automatic memory allocation/reallocation for outputs and automatic memory releasing.